# Adobe Dreamweaver - How to "move" images

Tags: html, move, image, dreamweaver

Adobe Dreamweaver - How to "move" images

i'm using HTML,and have three pictures that i want to move, and now it looks like this:
http://jonathangurebo.tumblr.com/post/41614799078

how to get it to be more nice. i want it to look like this:
http://jonathangurebo.tumblr.com/post/41614824708

how did i do? i'm a beginer with Dreamweaver.

My HTML code look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Jonathan Gurebo</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #191919;
}
-->
</style></head>

<body>
<center>
  <p><img src="Pictures/Jonathan Gurebo.png" width="405" height="76" />
  </p>
  <p><img src="Pictures/Apps.png" width="128" height="86" />f<img     src="Pictures/Contact.png" width="194" height="72" /></p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

As hunzaboy mentioned, adding a class and floats to these images is probably the quickest way of achieving your desired effect.

However, what I'd really recommend is possibly purchasing a book, like [HTML & CSS: Design and Build Web Sites](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/1118008189/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_N5vbrb0V1R8K7)

That one in particular is a brilliant book that will help you really understand the basics of HTML & CSS and the good practices to use when building your websites. Although Dreamweaver is good as an editor, when you're just a beginner to this you might want to learn more about how to code rather than using the visual editor.

As well as learning how to code for your own benefit, Dreamweaver's visual view doesn't always use the best standards - for example, it's adding the `<center>` tag in and adding a width and height to the images, when this should be achieved using CSS - which is the way to visually style your website.

If you'd rather learn online than through a book, you could also try out [Treehouse](http://www.teamtreehouse.com) or [Learn CSS on Tuts+](http://learncss.tutsplus.com/) - both are really great, affordable (or free) online courses that should help give you a much better understanding of what it is you're trying to do.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: Perfect answer. Tags like <center> should never be used, same for &nbsp;.

Answer (score 0):

the simple way is adding a class. and float the images left and right

.classname{float: left; display:block;}

or another simple way is create 3 divs ( in case you want to keep any text inbetween the two images ) an float them accordingly.

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Also as you are new to html so i suggest start learning via frameworks. http://getbootstrap.com is a great framework to start your website on a solid foundation.